# Journey Builder - What's the best way to let customers receive Email in a scheduled journey if they register after the journey started?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to send a bunch of emails to customers on different dates.
I am planning to create a journey, using "Wait Until Date" to schedule all the Email, but I am not sure if this is the best way, as I need to do this once a month.

Example:

- I start the journey on 1-Sep-2021, then in the journey, sending

  - Email A on 1-Sep
  - Email B on 5-Sep
  - Email C on 9-Sep etc.

How if I want the customer to receive the 5-Sep Email B if he is newly registered on my website on 3-Sep? He had missed out on the journey start data/entry date.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question - it's not possible to set it up that way. You either set it up as an ongoing journey and constantly let customers to be added and send them the emails on days 1, 5, and 9 (regardless of the date), or you schedule the journey to run once per month and in case someone registers after the journey has started, they get added to next mont's run.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is something totally normal for Journey Builder, but it's possible you need to think differently about how to schedule your wait activities, since you can configure a journey to enter users at any time.

**Wait until date** is typically used when the **wait period varies**, because users will enter a journey at different times but need to wait until a specific date before they proceed with the next activity. An example for this might be an event where everyone might be registering at different times, but everyone will get notified on the day of the event at the same time.

If the emails in your series need to be spaced out by a standard amount of days, then a **standard wait** activity will be sufficient. Your journey must be configured to run on an ongoing basis and [enter new contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&id=sf.mc_jb_entry_sources.htm&type=5) for example when they either are added to your entry data extension, when they're added via API call, or when they are added from a specific Salesforce Data event.